# Force10 S60 remote management

Tags: networking, switch, vlan, dell

We've got a Force10 S60 switch to replace an older Cisco. I can't find a way to give the switch itself an IP address on the local VLAN so I can ssh to it. The config guide talks about using either a management interface on a separate management network or dedicating e.g. a gigabit port as a management port with a dedicated IP address.  Ideally I would like to do what we do currently with the Cisco switches, which is in effect give the entire switch an IP so it can be reached from any host on the same VLAN without having to use up a physical port on the switch or physically connect the management port to another device.

Is this possible with the S60 and if so, how would you give it, say the address 10.0.1.1 in vlan 10 (10.0.1.1/24)?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You want to set up a VLAN, assign an IP to the VLAN, and then allocate all the interfaces on the switch to that VLAN.

```
Force10# conf t
Force10(conf)# interface range gigabitethernet 0/1 - 48
Force10(conf-if-range-gi-0/1-48)# switchport
Force10(conf-if-range-gi-0/1-48)# no shutdown
Force10(conf-if-range-gi-0/1-48)# exit
Force10(conf)# int vlan 10
Force10(conf-if-vlan)# untagged gi 0/1-48
Force10(conf-if-vlan)# ip address 10.0.1.1/24
Force10(conf-if-vlan)# exit
Force10(conf)#
```

You then have to enable the ssh server.

```
Force10(conf)# ip ssh server enable
Force10(conf)# ip ssh rsa-authentication enable
Force10(conf)# ip ssh server version 2
```

You should then be able to access the switch via SSH at 10.0.1.1 using a host plugged into the switch and in the same subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, it appears you are correct - the mgmt interface does not participate in the normal routing/switching table.  I would put a crossover cable between one of the "network" ports and connect it to the mgmt port.  Inelegant, wastes a port, but accomplishes what you want.

Comment: Thanks,  @Aaron. I had considered this, but after playing around with the config it looks like the management interface has to be in it's own subnet and I can't see a way of adding a route between that and a gigabit interface.  It's looking like it might have to be a physical link to a spare NIC on a box on the local VLAN and I will have to set that box up to NAT for the management network...  I really can't believe that Force10 would make such a limitation, surely? :-(

Comment: By separate subnet, do you mean that you're using the switch to do some routing as well?

Comment: I presume so as you either have to create a managementinterface followed by a managementroute (so it can reach the outside). Or use an existing non-management port and administer the switch through that. Try as I might, I can't get it to sit in my existing VLAN with my other cisco switches either using a management interface or a plain one as it then overlaps with the VLAN and that is not permitted. All I want is for the switch to exist in that VLAN without being connected to an individual host or using up physical connections...

Comment: I mean, if you're not using the switch for L3 routing, and all other machines in that subnet are 192.168.0.0/24, you can just do that crossover port for the mgmt port to a 'line' port and assign it 192.168.0.254/24 and default gateway however you choose.  But yes, that does use up a physical connection.  Seems to be "working as documented", unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the management interface, but, keep in mind that the Force 10 switches are layer 3 switches, not layer 2.  Where some switches may seem like you are assigning an IP to the "entire switch", any layer 3 Cisco switch would be setup more like Jerry's comment above. Using a dedicated management interface is best in environments where you have a separate and dedicated management network or VLAN - along with dedicated management switches.  In the absence of that, I would recommend that you shut down the management interface and set up a management VLAN on the switch.  Give the vlan an IP address and bring it up, then create an access list to protect your VTY access.  Also, keep in mind that, unlike a layer 3 Cisco switch, if you give IP addresses to multiple VLAN's on the Force 10, it will automatically begin routing.  There is no "IP Routing" command on the force 10 switches.  They assume if there is more than one IP address, you want to route.  That's one of the benefits of the management port - it won't route between the data and management planes. However, if you only give the switch one IP address, on the network that you use for management (which really shouldn't be on the same network as the data you are managing) the switch can't route because it only knows ONE layer 3 subnet.

kjp